# Transform elements in list in Python using Dataframe values?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a list in Python and I have a dataframe of values I want to transform them into:

```
fruits = ["cherry", "strawberry", "grape"]
```

| name | code |
| --- | --- |
| cherry | s1 |
| strawberry | s2 |
| apple | s3 |
| grape | s4 |

I would like to create a new list so that I achieve

```
newlist = ["s1", "s2", "s4"]
```

How would I do this in Python?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try using `.isin` and `loc` -

```
newlist = list(df.loc[df['name'].isin(fruits),'code'])
print(newlist)
```

```
['s1', 's2', 's4']
```

`df['name'].isin(fruits)` returns a boolean to check if the fruits in your list match with the columns. `df.loc` allow you to filter by those fruits and returns the values in column `code`